# Can apt-get purge be done with just apt?

Tags: debian, ubuntu, apt

I'm a bit confused around [`apt-get`](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/apt/apt-get.8.en.html) and [`apt`](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/apt/apt.8.en.html). Is `apt` an replacement of `apt-get` or just a similar tool? The reason why I'm asking is because it seems like most of the basic functionality in `apt-get` is also available in `apt` but there doesn't seem to be an `apt` equivalent to `apt-get purge`. What I like to do with `apt` is to uninstall a package and remove all of the config files in relation to the package being uninstalled.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/445384/what-is-the-difference-between-apt-and-apt-get

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting the [`apt` manpage](https://manpages.debian.org/apt#SCRIPT_USAGE):

> All features of `apt(8)` are available in dedicated APT tools like [`apt-get(8)`](https://manpages.debian.org/apt-get) and [`apt-cache(8)`](https://manpages.debian.org/apt-cache) as well. `apt(8)` just changes the default value of some options (see [`apt.conf(5)`](https://manpages.debian.org/apt.conf) and specifically the Binary scope).

`apt` is intended as a more user-friendly front-end, providing the same features as `apt-get` and `apt-cache`. The latter can’t be changes because they’re used in scripts and their interface is supposed to remain constant; `apt` is explicitly user-oriented and free to change to improve its user-friendliness.

The equivalent to `apt-get purge` is `apt purge`. It was added in [`apt` 0.9.14.3~exp3](https://tracker.debian.org/news/54874) in January 2014, and merged in the main branch in [`apt` 0.9.15](https://tracker.debian.org/news/54877) that same month, so any release of Debian or a derivative with a version of `apt` greater than or equal to 0.9.15 will have it — this includes Debian 8 (although the documentation doesn’t mention it), the forthcoming Debian 9, and versions of Ubuntu starting with 14.04.